# Custom fragment transition with kotlin

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension

Do you know how to inject custom transition animation to the underneath `replaceFragment()` method using kotlin?  It is a fragment to fragment transition

```
  private inline fun FragmentManager.inTransaction(func: FragmentTransaction.() -> FragmentTransaction) {
        beginTransaction().func().commit()
    }

    private fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment, frameId: Int) {
        supportFragmentManager.inTransaction { add(frameId, fragment) }
    }

    public fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment, frameId: Int) {
        supportFragmentManager
                .inTransaction { replace(frameId, fragment) 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution found:

```
private inline fun FragmentManager.inTransaction(func: FragmentTransaction.() -> FragmentTransaction) {
        beginTransaction()
                .func()
                .setCustomAnimations()
                .commit()
    }
```